# Using usort() with an object that implements ArrayIterator

Tags: php, arrays, usort

I have this class:

```
class ResultSet 
    implements ArrayAccess, Countable, Iterator {
     /// Rest of implementation ...
}
```

I'm running into a problem using usort() and passing my object as the first parameter. usort() expects an array instead of an object, but given my implementation of the `ArrayAccess` interface I don't know what else it could be needing.

The exact error returned by php is:
`Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given`.

Comment: Even `ArrayObject`'s suffer from this, I'd say it's either a bug or at least an unwanted legacy problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How would `usort` know how you've implemented `ArrayAccess`?  There is no defined place where the values are kept -- that flexibility is the whole point of the interface.

If you are storing the elements in an array that is a private member of the object, you could proxy the `usort` operation.  For example:

```
public function usort($callback) {
    usort($this->container, $callback);
}
```

Comment: I would have guessed that usort() could have internally called class_implements() (or something like that) and figure out if whatever you pass it can behave like an array. I also can't use a proxy since my internal array holds all sorts of different objects but I can think of something along that line. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, there's a big warning sign on the ArrayAccess page, or in one of the comments on it (probably the latter, in fact). It basically says something in the order of: the interface is somewhat useless, because PHP's array functions don't recognize any of its members as arrays.